# Getting Instagram Feeds on Facebook with PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram

I have a little question on some facebook development stuff. Currently I'm trying to get information about Photos that I posted via Instagram. I've tried it with the graph api:

```
<?php $status = $fb->api($fb->getUser().'/photos', 'GET'); ?>
<pre><?php print_r($status);?></pre>
```

But I don't get information about posts that were done by using other apps. Everything else show up just fine. The permissions I required are: user_status, user_photos, friends_photos'

Where could the problem source be?

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody who is facing the same issue. It's an approved bug: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/202119973248747?browse=search_5001dc2ee99a53e97238451